# how to initialize environmental variables and how to understand simulation module in python?

Tags: python

First question:
I have a python program and after I run it, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myfile.py", line 242, in <module>
     out_dir = os.path.join( dir, "myfile-{0}".format(os.environ['JOB_ID']) )

  File "/apps/x86_64/python 2.7.6/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in _getitem_ 
  raise KeyError(key)
  KeyError: 'JOB_ID'
```

Is it because I did not initialize the environmental variables in the command line prompt? The `UserDict` is involved with a dictionary, right?

Second question:
How to quickly grasp the main initialization of a simulation in python? For example, suppose I have the following code.

```
sim= Simulation.Simulation ( { key : value }, a, TIME_STEP_SIZE, expected_rates_LogisticRK4 )
```

How to understand this then? I am relatively new to python. Many thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: 1) One question per post. 2) If some code is throwing an exception, *post that code*. It's hard to debug code we can't see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should split your question into two, however, for the first question, the exception is raised because there is no `JOB_ID` environment variable set in your Python program's environment. Firstly you can set it on the command line when invoking Python:

```
$ JOB_ID=100 python myfile.py
```

or you can set the variable in you shell's environment:

```
$ export JOB_ID=100
$ python myfile.py
```

Either of these will fix the problem, however, you should code more defensively by catching the exception, or by using `os.environ.get('JOB_ID')` which will not throw an exception if the environment variable is not set.

For the second question you should reask it as new question and in it explain more accurately which module is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use os.getenv('JOB_ID') instead of os.environ['JOB_ID']. Tell me how are you setting the environment variable from the command-line? For ex.: you could do this:

```
export JOB_ID=testjob; python filename.py
```